# Springboot application doesn't get deployed on Wildfly

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, wildfly

I am trying to deploy a simple Spring Boot application on Wildfly(Wildfly 13), I am trying to deploy it locally on Eclipse but nothing loads up. When I try to open the webpage I am getting 403 error.

Here's the POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>demo</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Application Class

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.example.demo")
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<DemoApplication> applicationClass = DemoApplication.class;
}
```

Controller Class

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello/{name}")
    String hello(@PathVariable String name) {

        System.out.println("In the Controller");
        return "Hi " + name + " !";

    }
}
```

Wildfly Log

```
22:17:49,850 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.8.5.Final
22:17:50,173 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.2.Final
22:17:50,181 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.3.2.Final
22:17:50,277 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 13.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 5.0.0.Final) starting
22:17:51,504 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
22:17:51,524 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 7) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.3.3.Final
22:17:51,526 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 8) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
22:17:51,549 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found hello.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called hello.war.dodeploy
22:17:51,597 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
22:17:51,616 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO version 3.6.3.Final
22:17:51,622 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.6.3.Final
22:17:51,652 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
22:17:51,653 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
22:17:51,663 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
22:17:51,663 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.5.1.Final
22:17:51,673 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
22:17:51,680 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
22:17:51,686 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
22:17:51,689 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.9.Final)
22:17:51,705 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.2.Final
22:17:51,730 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ee] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYEE0119: The system property 'ee8.preview.mode' is NOT set to 'true'. For provided EE 8 APIs where the EE 8 version of the API differs from what is supported in EE 7, the EE 7 variant of the API will be used. Support for this setting will be removed once all EE 8 APIs are provided and certified.
22:17:51,750 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 2.0.9.Final starting
22:17:51,788 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
22:17:51,807 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
22:17:51,808 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
22:17:51,811 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
22:17:52,000 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\Users\abc\wildfly-13.0.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
22:17:52,221 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 16 core threads with 128 task threads based on your 8 available processors
22:17:52,227 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 32 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
22:17:52,227 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 128 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
22:17:52,274 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.7.Final
22:17:52,309 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
22:17:52,319 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
22:17:52,362 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYPAT0050: WildFly Full cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
22:17:52,378 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 0.0.0.0:28080
22:17:52,390 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
22:17:52,400 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYDM0111: Keystore C:\Users\abc\wildfly-13.0.0.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
22:17:52,412 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\abc\wildfly-13.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments
22:17:52,644 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "hello.war" (runtime-name: "hello.war")
22:17:52,684 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
22:17:52,906 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 0.0.0.0:28443
22:17:52,969 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.2.1.Final (Apache CXF 3.2.4.jbossorg-1) 
22:17:53,594 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Gaina' 9.2.4.Final
22:17:53,743 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
22:17:53,874 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/hello' for server 'default-server'
22:17:53,885 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "hello.war" (runtime-name : "hello.war")
22:17:53,940 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
22:17:53,942 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
22:17:53,942 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
22:17:53,943 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 13.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 5.0.0.Final) started in 4439ms - Started 393 of 670 services (404 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

When I try the same application with Tomcat(run as Spring Boot App) from Eclipse, the program runs fine. I am relatively new developing the Spring Boot Applications, I can't seem to understand the dependency properly.

Here's the POM when I try with Tomcat

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>hello</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Log of the Application when run with Tomcat

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)

2020-03-29 19:57:18.773  INFO 13472 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on OLA-3XQ41Z2 with PID 13472 (C:\opt\scripts\development\workspace\demo\target\classes started by abc in C:\opt\scripts\development\workspace\demo)
2020-03-29 19:57:18.775  INFO 13472 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-29 19:57:19.302  INFO 13472 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-03-29 19:57:19.307  INFO 13472 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-03-29 19:57:19.308  INFO 13472 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
2020-03-29 19:57:19.354  INFO 13472 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-03-29 19:57:19.354  INFO 13472 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 552 ms
2020-03-29 19:57:19.468  INFO 13472 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-03-29 19:57:19.540  WARN 13472 --- [           main] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2020-03-29 19:57:19.594  INFO 13472 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-03-29 19:57:19.596  INFO 13472 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 1.014 seconds (JVM running for 1.537)
2020-03-29 19:57:24.869  INFO 13472 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-03-29 19:57:24.869  INFO 13472 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-03-29 19:57:24.873  INFO 13472 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 4 ms
In the Controller
```

Appreciate any inputs as of why the Application fails to deploy.

Thanks in advance!!

Update on 3/30:
I had to add my comments here as the short comments aren't helping me.

Thanks @Ananthapadmanabhan whatever you suggested helped. I tried to extend the POM for an application I built now I am getting `Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory from [Module "deployment.supplier.war"` error.

Here are the things I added to POM.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
            <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: If your original issue is resolved please mark the accepted answer and create a separate question with the updated pom and stacktrace. We must follow the stackoverflow guidelines .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to use `undertow` or external `wildfly` server for deployment. If you want to use wildfly exclude the undertow dependency from your pom.

If you are using the Wildfly application server, Undertow is already the default web server in the Wildfly Application Server. So , there is no need for you to specify undertow as an embedded server. If you do that, it won't work. So just use the `provided` scope only.But if you do that , you don't need to specify the `javax-servlet`.Try providing either of the two in the `pom.xml`. Either of the two can be used at compile time to build the artifact . But if you want to keep the `war` size small use the `servlet` dependency.

Try the following pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>demo</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `wildfly-maven-plugin` in the configuration

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2.Final</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <filename>${project.build.finalName}.war</filename>
                    <hostname>${deploy.jboss.host}</hostname>
                    <port>${deploy.jboss.port}</port>
                    <username>${deploy.jboss.username}</username>
                    <password>${deploy.jboss.password}</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Look at [this](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-deploy-spring-boot-application-in-wildfly-application-server-b3670c031ad4) tutorial to configure